# Como se dice realmente, Bibliotecas o Librerias

Tags: php, javascript, java, html, jquery

Mi pregunta es, como es la manera correcta de decir, Libreria o Bibliotecas de programación.

Por ejemplo, la manera correcta de decirle a React es.
 - Es un framework
 - Es Una Libreria?
 - Es Una Biblioteca?

Saludos

Comment: Cuando indica que es *a JavaScript library* se refiere a *una biblioteca JavaScript* a mi parecer es un error de traducción usar de manera indistinta librería y biblioteca

Comment: es irrelevante ya que library = biblioteca, pero llendonos a alglisismos sulen tomarlo por libreria...

Comment: React no es un framework...

Comment: Me parece que las posibles respuestas a esta pregunta pueden estar basadas en opiniones. Estaría bien que revises: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic)

Comment: En informática, una biblioteca o, llamada por vicio del lenguaje librería (del inglés library) es un conjunto de implementaciones funcionales, codificadas en un lenguaje de programación, que ofrece una interfaz bien definida para la funcionalidad que se invoca. Cualquiera de los dos términos que uses es correcto, se refieren a lo mismo.

Comment: Si opinan que esta pregunta es pertinente, lo discutimos en meta, pero parece una excelente pregunta para [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Librería en español es un lugar donde compras libros.
 Library en inglés, que es como se llama a los componentes que usamos para aplicaciones, quiere decir biblioteca.
Así, el término correcto en español es biblioteca, porque no tomas el componente y te lo llevas, sino que lo pides prestado.

la confusión del uso viene del parecido entre las dos palabras en inglés y español, se dejó de usar biblioteca por usar librería al no conocer el significado en inglés y creer que era la traducción correcta.

Framework es un conjunto de bibliotecas, aplicaciones y artefactos que te permiten implementar completamente alguna aplicación, ej. .Net.
Como te han comentado, React es una biblioteca que se usa sólo para crear front end para web apps, y no te obliga a usar componentes específicos para servicios http, validaciones, conexiones a datos.

Comment: Libreria en español también es un mueble donde poner los libros o un conjunto de libros. Lo de la tienda solo es una acepción.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, ese se llama librero :)